# LINQ DB Arithmetic must have common type (Date Comparison

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get the record from a database with the highest amount of days using a start and end date. I keep getting a System.Argument.Exception in the Entity.dll.

The error states:

```
{"DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type."}
```

Here is my LINQ statement:

```
var maxDaysTask = whseTasks.Where(x => x.CompDate != null && x.TaskDate != null).Max(x => ((DateTime)x.TaskDate - (DateTime)x.CompDate).TotalDays);
```

The CompDate(end date) and TaskDate(begin date) are both nullable datetimes. Any advice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use subtraction in a query: the `operator -` is overloaded in .NET, but not in the SQL Server.

You can use [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve the effect that you are looking for:

```
var maxDaysTask = whseTasks
    .Where(x => x.CompDate != null && x.TaskDate != null)
    .Max(x => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", x.TaskDate, x.CompDate));
```

Comment: I get {"'days' is not a valid value for the DATEPART argument in the 'SqlServer.DATEDIFF' function."}

Comment: @user3788671 Oops, it should be `"day"`, not `"days"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the built-in functions of `Nullable<T>` such as the `HasValue` property to check for null in this situation.  Since these are nullable structs you usually can't access the internal values, which is why you are erroring.  Make sure you use the `Value` property to get the actual DateTime struct

```
var maxDaysTask = whseTasks.Where(x => x.CompDate.HasValue && x.TaskDate.HasValue)
                            .Max(x => (x.TaskDate.Value - x.CompDate.Value).TotalDays);
```